# How are these values calculated in Python Scapy?

Tags: python, networking, ip, scapy

I am curious about the values of the `chksum` and how it is calculated.

```
###[ IP ]### 
     chksum    = 0x95d3

###[ UDP ]### 
     chksum    = 0x1a77
```

What is `chksum=0x1a77` and `chksum=0x95d3` how are they calculated in python Scapy? I need some explanation for these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value is a [CheckSum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checksum), and they are used to verify that a sequence of data has or has not changed since the last time the checksum was calculated. The network packet/segment has a checksum field in the header, and when your system recieves the datagram, it recalculates the checksum to determine whether it is still equal to to value in the header field. If it is, then you can make a basic inference that the data is unchanged. Checksums are a weak validation, but they are cheap to perform, so for the right task, they can provide a good balance for verifying data integrity vs effort required.

The mechanism is similar for the [IP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_checksum), [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol), and [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) checksums.

From [RFC 791 page 14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_checksum) (IP):

> ```
> Header Checksum:  16 bits
>
> A checksum on the header only.  Since some header fields change
> (e.g., time to live), this is recomputed and verified at each point
> that the internet header is processed.
>
> The checksum algorithm is:
>
>   The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
>   complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header.  For purposes of
>   computing the checksum, the value of the checksum field is zero.
>
> This is a simple to compute checksum and experimental evidence
> indicates it is adequate, but it is provisional and may be replaced
> by a CRC procedure, depending on further experience.
> ```

from [RFC 768 page 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc768) (UDP):

> ```
> Checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement sum of
> a pseudo header of information from the IP header, the UDP header, and
> the data,  padded  with zero octets  at the end (if  necessary)  to 
> make  a multiple of two octets.
> ```

From [RFC 793 page 16](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793) (TCP):

> ```
> Checksum:  16 bits
>
> The checksum field is the 16 bit one's complement of the one's
> complement sum of all 16 bit words in the header and text.  If a
> segment contains an odd number of header and text octets to be
> checksummed, the last octet is padded on the right with zeros to
> form a 16 bit word for checksum purposes.  The pad is not
> transmitted as part of the segment.  While computing the checksum,
> the checksum field itself is replaced with zeros.
> ```

and the efficient calculation of the checksum is discussed in [RFC 1071](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1071) "Computing the Internet Checksum". Its somewhat involved, but the math behind the theory and some code implementations are contained therein.

Comment: do i have to know all that ? or it is not necessary ?

Comment: I never have. i know what a checksum is, and what they are for, and that has been sufficient for me, as I'm not implementing an IP stack. Its not clear from your question what you are trying to get out of it, or why, so we can't really answer that question for you.

Comment: i just wanna know what this 0x95d3 is, it is really confusing me